# change Time inside object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

My code creates an event inside Google Calendar, I need to get the value of start time and add 2 hours to get my end time.

Here's an example of the array my function returns:

```
[[kljlkjl, Manaf, Tue Jun 25 16:00:00 GMT+03:00 2019]]
```

This is part of the code that I want to fix:

```
  var data = ss.getRange("A"+activeRow+":G"+activeRow).getValues();

   if(cellContent === "Manaf") {
       Logger.log(data);
       Manaf.createEvent(data[0][0],data[0][2],data[0][2],{description: "First call "+ data[0][0]}) ;
```

Comment: Hi, Manaf! I am not sure I correctly understand what you're trying to do here, but if you just need the time to change to two hours late, you can use the pairing `getHours()` -> `setHours()` on the output date. Please, let me know if this is the case - if so, I'll get in detail in the answer

Comment: After further examination of your script, decided to post the answer just in case, hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Oleg,  see I have in cell "dd/mm/yyyy    hh:mm:ss" my function parse the entire row and arenge it to title, start time & end time to use it inside google calender. I don't won't to create another column for end time so I just need to use start time culumn +2 hours . to here is ok when I log the function the array above is printed, so I want to change date[0][2]  which is this "Tue Jun 25 16:00:00 GMT+03:00 2019"  to  "Tue Jun 25 18:00:00 GMT+03:00 2019"

 I hope you understand what I want to do

Comment: Thanks! I understood you correctly then - please, see my answer on how to proceed  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

To increment hours by 2, you can utilize `getHours()` and `setHours()` methods of the `Date` built-in object with the instance written into `data` variable. As you need to increment hours dynamically, you’ll have to pair these methods like this: `dateInstance.setHours(dateInstance.getHours()+2)`.

**Sample**

So, your script with this modification will look like this (please, note that I also updated your code to work directly with 1-d `Array` as your range is always one-row):

```
var data  = ss.getRange("A"+activeRow+":G"+activeRow).getValues()[0];
var start = data[2];
var end   = new Date(start); //create new Date to persist start;
    end.setHours(start.getHours()+2); //add 2 hours;

if(cellContent === "Manaf") {
  Manaf.createEvent(data[0],start,end,{description: "First call "+ data[0]});
}
```

**Useful links**

1. `Date` built-in object [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date);
2. `getHours()` method [deeplink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours);
3. `setHours()` method [deeplink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours);